# Verify ethers.js signature in backend with web3.py

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I'm trying to implement a 'Login with Metamask' button on my dapp.

On the frontend I'm using ethers.js code:

```
 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    var [account] = await ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_requestAccounts'
    });

    
 const signer = provider.getSigner(account);
 signature = await signer.signMessage("Hello World");
```

This as expected, generates a signed message hash (lets assume its: 0xec325c188547379c92df21225c624206ba68bb2a87994c7e2937375ad6fbe609109780a5ed6e9633c132708fd66d6edf2bd993e9ce346797e7e33448639f751d1c)

On the backend, I want to use web3.py to verify this address.

```
message_hash = web3.keccak(text="Hello World")
signature = 0xec325c188547379c92df21225c624206ba68bb2a87994c7e2937375ad6fbe609109780a5ed6e9633c132708fd66d6edf2bd993e9ce346797e7e33448639f751d1c
web3.eth.account.recoverHash(message_hash, signature=signature)
```

However, this doesnt quite work, and the address I receive back is different to the address that signed the original message.

```
>>> web3.eth.account.recoverHash(message, signature=signature)
'0xAA1A56093f7Dd7a8Df755c616ccdc295e0a2af5f'
>>>
```

How do I correctly verify the signature in web3.py and return the correct address that signed 'Hello World' in the frontend ethers.js code?

Comment: Thanks for also sharing your findings helped me in my search! Rep to low comment or +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to the wonderful chinese website that explained this well and I figured it out.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import sys
from eth_account.messages import defunct_hash_message

w3 = Web3() 

signature = sys.argv[1]

original_message = "Hello World"
message_hash = defunct_hash_message(text=original_message)

signer = w3.eth.account.recoverHash(message_hash, signature=signature)
return signer
```